# Align fixed div tag percentage

Tags: html, alignment, fixed, percentage

I have two `<div>` tags (one fixed, the other relative, and both floated).
I want to align them side by side by percentage

Here is the example

```
<style>
#mainDiv{
    width:80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 200px;
}
#fixedDiv{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color:red;
    position: fixed;
    height: inherit;
}
#relativeDiv{
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    background-color:blue;
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
}
</style>
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="fixedDiv">Fixed DIV</div>
    <div id="relativeDiv">Relative DIV</div>
</div>
```

Also http://jsfiddle.net/v1noqz2g/

Comment: its aligned ! why u're trying to say ?

Comment: first div is 30%, second 70% ... but there are overlaped

Comment: you cannot float a `position:fixed` element. Also when the screen is scrolled, they won't be side by side anymore

Comment: The reason your div overlaps is because when you make a div position:fixed it becomes relative to the body so its width will be 30% of the body rather than 30% of the containing div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just reduce `width` size in `#relativeDiv` to `width:62%;` or adjust it